# No U+2003 in Latin Modern Roman 12 Regular

Tags: unicode, latin-modern

I am using the OTF variant of the Latin Modern Fonts on my system (Linux Ubuntu) with `XeLaTex`. http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

I cannot set an Em Space : https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+2003
since there is a warning

```
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no   (U+2003) (U+2003) in font Latin Modern Roman 12 Regular
```

Why is this? I thought the font was Unicode capable?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  paper=a4,
  twoside,
  titlepage=true,
  openright,
  abstract=on,
  toc=listofnumbered,
  numbers=noenddot,
  chapterprefix=true,
  headings=optiontohead,
  svgnames,
  dvipsnames]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
  \setmainfont[]{Latin Modern Roman}
  \setsansfont[]{Latin Modern Sans}
  \setmonofont[]{Latin Modern Mono}
  \setmathfont[]{Latin Modern Math}


\begin{document}
EN space     
\end{document}
```

Comment: no font has every unicode character (there are more Unicode character slots than the font format supports, and most font designers only design fonts for specific scripts so a subset of Unicode) so you will always potentially get missing character errors.  Also spaces are usually don in TeX with `\hspace{1em}` no by adding a character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because a font is “Unicode capable” doesn't mean it has to support every single glyph. The easiest `LaTeX` way in my opinion would be to simply use `\quad`.

That said, if you regularly have these kind of spaces in your document and want to deal with them automatically, check out the `uspace` (as in “Unicode Space”) package. https://ctan.org/pkg/uspace

It also supports zero width space (U+200B), three-per-em space (U+2004), four-per-em space, thin space (U+2009), hair space (U+200A) and others and works with all fonts.

Answer (score 8):

TeX doesn't consider spaces as characters. You can obtain the same result by doing

```
\catcode"2003=\active
\protected\def^^^^2003{\quad}
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\catcode"2003=\active
\protected\def^^^^2003{\quad}

\begin{document}

EN space

EN\quad space% for check

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion, typing in `\quad` is much clearer.